# Avoid inf massage as a output for a large numer of output in PHP

Tags: php, function, output

This is a very simple code for print out factorial value.
How can i avoid `inf` message  when i want to print something like this.
399603090!
ans-7.257415615308E+306.

```
 <?php
    $n=readline("enter the number:");
    $f=1;
    for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
    {
        $f=$f*$i;
    }
    echo $f
    ?>
```

Comment: Maybe check that the value is lower than `PHP_INT_MAX`?

Comment: with normal value its work totally fine.but i have to submit assignment ): with large value ):

Comment: What is the assignment? Seems like you are exceeding PHP integer size.

Comment: Take two number M and N, where one number either M
or N is less than or equal to 170 and other number is
any size integer number. You will find the GCD of M!
(M factorial) and N! (N factorial) using PHP.
Suppose M = 4 and N = 3. Then 4! = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 and 3!
= 3 * 2 * 1. So, the GCD of 24 and 6 is 6.
If M = 170 and N = 399603090 then GCD of 170! And
399603090! is 7.257415615308E+306.

Comment: What do you mean by "inf massage"?

Comment: @NicoHaase Use a number larger than `170` for the loop and you'll get the `inf` back for `$f`.

Comment: @SiumHossain https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-integers-floats-and-number-strings--cms-32048#:~:text=In%20PHP%2C%20any%20numerical%20value,()%20and%20is_infinite()%20functions. Maybe tell the user the PHP cant process for the number the user has input? I'm interested about the `less than or equal to 170`, 170 is the limit for your problem perhaps professor knows that? Maybe `$n` should be used for the start and it should run until 170?